# Why this method to modify a function's arguments array fails when a param is omitted?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm modifying several functions of some "core" JS software using "hijacking":

```
var orig_func = func; // initially function(a,b,c,d)

func = function(a,b,c,d) {
    // modify arguments
    d = someCustomization(c,d);
    // do additional stuff
    doSomethingCustom(a);
    // apply the original "core" function
    return orig_func.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

which works nicely *unless* the modified params are optional: calling

```
func(a,b);
```

works in a way that `d` is `undefined` even though `someCustomization` returns something else when both its arguments are `undefined`.

Here's an MVCE for using in cosole:

```
var f = function(optionalParam){ if(optionalParam) console.log(optionalParam); };
var orig_f = f;
f = function(optionalParam){
    optionalParam = optionalParam ? 'custom: '+optionalParam : 'default';
    orig_f.apply(this, arguments);
};
f(); // shows undefined
f('test'); // shows 'custom: test'
```

"Expected" behaviour is to see `"default"` in console in the first case, but I get `undefined` instead.

After some experiments and using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13610987/3995261) where I've summarized adding a positioned param in a [corresponding answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340230/3995261) I've come with the following solution in terms of MCVE:

```
var f = function(some,optionalParam){
    console.log('some:',some);
    console.log('optionalParam:',optionalParam);
};
var orig_f = f;
f = function(some,optionalParam){
    if(optionalParam)
        optionalParam = 'custom: '+optionalParam;
    else {
        var argPosition = 2;
        while(arguments.length < argPosition)
            [].push.call(arguments,undefined);
        arguments[argPosition-1] = 'default';
    }
    orig_f.apply(this, arguments);
};
f(); // shows 'some: undefined' and 'optionalParam: default'
```

or in terms of the initial task:

```
var orig_func = func; // initially function(a,b,c,d)

func = function(a,b,c,d) {
    // modify arguments
    while(arguments.length < 4)
        [].push.call(arguments,undefined);
    arguments[3] = someCustomization(c,d);
    // do additional stuff
    doSomethingCustom(a);
    // apply the original "core" function
    return orig_func.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

But I'm not really able to explain what's the problem with the initial approach: why it worked for required (used) params and failed for an optional (unused) one? Does it have anything to do with closures? Why `d` is "not connected" with `arguments` in the second case?

Comment: You're not actually modifying `arguments`, you just assign to the local variables? The "connection" to the arguments object is deprecated and only works in sloppy mode. Don't use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, with the help of georg ("magic bindings" keyword) and some more research I've come to an almost sufficient explanation:

- in the *old* standart (haven't found which one, though) argument variables (`a,b,c,d`) and `arguments[i]` point to the same values (*not sure how this is done in JS*, though)

  - in the *new* standart this is not so (like Bergi has said, it is deprecated): changing `arguments[0]` won't affect `a` and vise versa; like georg said, it is so in the strict mode:

    ```
    function f(x) {
        "use strict";
        arguments[0] = 5;
        console.log( x );
    }
    f(1); // logs 1
    ```
- now when all variables are present, both `a,b,c,d` (as variables scoped to the function) and `arguments[1-4]` are defined and connected pairwise pointing to the same values. When params `c` and `d` are omitted, `arguments[3]` and `arguments[4]` are not defined and even if we define them, there's no "connection" between them and the variables (again, I'm *not sure if such connection can be created manually*)
- basic recomendation is if we need to modify arguments, we should either use only `arguments` (and `.apply` them) or only local variables (and use `.call`) or mix them but don't rely on the connection between them

Answer (score 3):

`arguments` "magic bindings" are created by iterating actual arguments, so if an arg is not there, no binding will be created:

```js
function a(x, y) {
    y = 42;
    console.log(arguments)
}

a(10, 20)
a(10)
```

That said, using magic bindings is a bad idea, and they won't work in the strict mode anyways. If the number of arguments is known beforehand, simply do

```
orig_func.call(this, a, b, c, d);
```

otherwise use a splat `...args` and manipulate that.